# How to solve net::ERR_TIMED_OUT in axios post call?

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

```
             Axios.post(`https://16.16.6.1:8000/api/login`, { 
                    username: "userName",
                    password: "password"
                })
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log("Logging in")
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        alert(err.message)
                    })
```

Earlier I used to use backend which was running in my own system so used to use localhost or window.location.hostname in place of specific hostname address like "16.16.6.1". I wanted to access the Django server running on this host, it was giving me this error.

Comment: did you try to call this API from postman or any other tool? Is it working fine with same url, request type and request body?

Comment: Did you tried to make the call to http instead of https protocol?

Comment: @SAJJADALI It gives me error in postman; Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Comment: @Khorne07 yes, it is the same case.

Comment: it means there is no issue with axios call. You need to fix your connection problems. As @Khorne07 said. make sure that HTTPS is working on your machine. or try with http only.